# How to get event when application is closed from task manager?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-vista

I have developed a Win32 application using C/C++, which runs on Vista and XP.

I wanted to know, can I get any event in my application when my application is killed from task manager, by selecting the "end process" button?

I want to free some memory on exit of my application.

Comment: @Vinayaka Karjigi - generally one only needs to use the end process option when the application is hung, so ideally if such a need arise there is some prob with your application which may require a relook. Like pointed in the answers below, memory cleanup will be done by OS when it terminates the process. When it does again depends on OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, your application is terminated without any notice. You are at mercy of Task Manager.

Comment: And the OS will free the memory anyway so catching it to free memory is ENTIRELY pointless.

Answer (score 0):

In .net 2.0 you can get closing reason of [CloseReason.TaskManagerClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason.aspx). Therefore I suspect there is a [structured exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657(VS.85).aspx) you should be able to handle.

Edit. [Possibly not](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=362660&seqNum=6)

I suspect that the CLR places break point on NTTerminateProcess for managed processes.